# saving image into ravendb using attachments

Tags: .net, winforms, ravendb

I'm looking for practical example of storing image into raven database using ravendb attachments. I've just read the http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/attachments and I  have simple question.

If I use poco class should I use property of type `byte[]` to store image into db, for example

```
public int id {get; set;}
...
public byte[] image {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you most definitely shouldn't. Attachments are a concept separate from your POCOs. You should store the attachment ID as string with your POCOs, if at all. Having a byte[] property in your POCO will bloat the document unnecessarily.

My advice would be to skip attachments and store binaries on the cloud instead - this is also what I wrote in that doc you referred to.

But if you are going to reference an attachment from a POCO, do this using a string reference.